# why it says can't convert string to int type when used int a = Integer.parseInt(System.in.read());

Tags: java, runtime-error

i am unable to understand where it is going wrong, since `System.in.read()` gives ascii no as string so using `Integer.parseInt` it must be solved and it must return the value entered on console..

when i compile it throws error cannot convert `String` to `int` type..

please check and tell where i gone wrong..

```
import java.io.IOException;

class AB 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(System.in.read()); 

        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.in.read()` returns an `int`, `parseInt` expects a `String`. The actual error is "_int cannot be converted to java.lang.String_".

Comment: You should probably be using a Scanner to read an int from stdin : `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); if (sc.hasNextInt()){ int a = sc.nextInt(); /*[...]*/ };`